# Getting exception while converting the dates in Java

Tags: java, date, exception

I am trying to convert the below mentioned date into yyyMMdd by using below mentioned code.

```
String dateString = "1st August 2012";
SimpleDateFormat simp_date=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
    try
    {
        dateString=simp_date.format(new Date(dateString));
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I am getting below excpetion.

IllegalArgumentException

Could someone help me out ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: shoudln't your date should be in the same format as you've created in SimpleDateFormat constructor?

Comment: @PrasadKharkar He wants to format that date to the given format. He rather needs another `SimpleDateFormat` instance for parsing the give dateString

Comment: "1 August 2012".  Drop the "st".

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you should not use the constructor [`Date(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date%28java.lang.String%29), as it's deprecated. What you need here is to first parse the date string using a format to convert it to a `Date` object, and then format that `Date` object to the required format.

The following code would work:

```
String dateString = "1st August 2012";

// Format for parsing the dateString
SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("d'st' MMM yyyy");

// To format the resultant Date object to new String format
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");

try {
    dateString = formatter.format(parser.parse(dateString));

} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println(dateString);
```

I would suggest you to move towards [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), a much powerful DateTime API than Java's `Date` and `Calendar`. You will be surprised how easy it is to work with dates with that. In fact Java 8 introduces a completely new datetime API based on JodaTime only.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rohit. I'll check the new API.

Comment: is there a way by which I can make this code more generic instead of passing "d'st' MMM yyyy", that should work for all the dates(For eg. : 2nd,3rd and 4th)?

Comment: @Technocrat No, that's not possible. You have to maintain an array of different data formats, and try each of them in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try this buddy

```
java.util.Date  ss1=new Date("Sat Dec 01 00:00:00 GMT 2012");
SimpleDateFormat formatter5=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String formats1 = formatter5.format(ss1);
System.out.println(formats1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code
`String date = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(2, 2, Locale.US).format(new Date());`

The output will be Nov 15, 2013 2:06:00 PM

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested but I little modified **ROHIT's** code:

Can You test following code? Pls...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] s1 = {"st", "nd", "rd", "th"};
    String dateString = "1st August 2012";
    for (Object obj : s1) {
        SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("d'" + obj + "' MMM yyyy");
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
        try {
            dateString = formatter.format(parser.parse(dateString));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Expected OutPut:::" + dateString);
}
```